# Subtracting consecutive elements in a list when the first element is great than the next - Python

Tags: python, list, performance, loops, subtraction

I'm making a program which completes the following:

When inputted a list `a`, it will subtract consecutive elements (starting from the beginning) if the results are non-negative numbers.
For example, if

```
a=[3,2,1]
```

then consecutive numbers will be subtracted, so `a=[1,1]`, and then `a=[0]`. Also, in the result, all numbers must be ascending (for example a `2,1` cannot be in the list). Another example:

```
a=[1, 10, 7, 3, 2]
[1, 3, 3, 2] #10-7 (10 and 7 get replaced with 3)
[1, 0, 2]    #3-3  (precedence goes to the left: 3-3 gets subtracted, not 3-2)
[1, 2]       #1-0
```

Here is my current code (where a is being generated randomly):

```
import random
a=[random.randint(1,10) for e in range(20)]
print(a)
loop=1
while True:
    try:
        #print(loop,a)
        subloop=0
        while subloop<loop:
            if a[loop-subloop]<=a[loop-1-subloop]:
                a[loop-1-subloop]=a[loop-1-subloop]-a.pop(loop-subloop)
                if loop!=1:
                    loop-=1
            subloop+=1
        if a[loop]<=a[loop-1]:
            a[loop-1]=a[loop-1]-a.pop(loop)
        else:
            loop+=1
    except IndexError:
        break
print(a)
```

This code feels kind of long/ineffiecient. Is there a better or more short/efficient way to do this?

Comment: Shouldn't the first example end at `[0]`?  `[3, 2, 1]` -> `[1, 1]` -> `[0]`

Comment: Yup. Sorry for that

Comment: In your example, why didn't you do `10-7` and `3-2`? Is there only one subtraction per iteration?

Comment: Even if you did do that, doesn't it still end up with `[1,2]`. I'm not sure if it makes a difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my take on it:

```
a = [1, 10, 7, 3, 2]
b = [3, 2, 1]


def index_helper(l):
    for i, x in enumerate(l[:-1]):
        if l[i] >= l[i+1]:
            return i


def reduce(l):
    i = index_helper(l)
    while i is not None:
        l[i:i + 2] = [l[i] - l[i + 1]]
        i = index_helper(l)
    return l


>>> reduce(a)
[1, 2]

>>> reduce(b)
[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative solution:

```
def my_func(a):
    next_i = next((i for i in range(len(a)-1) if (a[i] - a[i+1]) >=0), None)
    while next_i is not None:
        a = a[:next_i] + [a[next_i] - a[next_i+1]] + a[next_i+2:]
        next_i = next((i for i in range(len(a)-1) if (a[i] - a[i+1]) >=0), None)
    return a

print(my_func(a=[1, 10, 7, 3, 2]))
#[1, 2]

print(my_func(a=[3, 2, 1]))
#[0]
```

However, this is slightly slower than @bphi's solution:

```
import random
N = 10000
a_list = [[random.randint(1,10) for e in range(20)] for _ in range(N)]

all([reduce(l) == my_func(l) for l in a_list])  # verify answers are same
#True

%%timeit
[my_func(l) for l in a_list]
#10.7 ms ± 358 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit
[reduce(l) for l in a_list]
#7.51 ms ± 416 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```